# How to tell in C# whether GPS shapes intersect?

Tags: c#, .net, gis

If I have two WTK (well known text) shapes in C# how can I tell if these intersect?

For instance are there any libraries, or are there any standard algorithms?

I might also need to do this using a group of points like this for each shape,

```
    public double[] Eastings { get; set; }
    public double[] Northings { get; set; }
```

Comment: Check out point in polygon algorithms. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon for an overview of how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the [.NET topology suite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/), which implements WKT parsing and full topology operations such as Intersect and Overlaps tests. I haven't actually used the .NET version, but I've used its predecessor the Java Topology Suite (JTS) and it's worked very well for me.